# Looping in the Naming of Variables and Filenames

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, naming

I am looking to see if the following code can be condensed. I know I need to use arrays and a loop statement, but what I have tried has not worked. I usually get an error saying I can't use a list where a string or interval is supposed to be, which probably means looping isn't actually occurring?

```
writef1startsw1pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw1.txt", "w")
writef1startsw2pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw2.txt", "w")
writef1startsw3pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw3.txt", "w")
writef1startsw4pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw4.txt", "w")
writef1startsw5pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw5.txt", "w")
writef1startsw6pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw6.txt", "w")
writef1startsw7pt1 = open("C:/f1startsw7.txt", "w")
```

The only things that need to be changed are the number in the variable, and the number in the filename, ranging from 1 to 7.

I'm sure the solution isn't too complicated, but I've spent a while trying to figure this out, and I'm still stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use numbered variables. Use a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

Variable name substitution like that is not possible in Python, however, you can use a list to achieve the same goal.

```
writef1startswpt1 = []
for i in range (1,8):
    writef1startswpt1.append(open("C:/f1startsw" + str(i)+ ".txt", "w"))

#Now you have a list of those 7 open files, and you can access them with the indices 0 - 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary instead of a list to keep track of the files, since list indices start at 0 while your files start at 1 (or you could use simply keep a `None` entry at index 0.

```
files = {}
for i in range(1, 7+1):
    files["writef1startsw{}pt1".format(i)] = open("C:/f1startsw{}.txt".format(i), "w")

files["writef1startsw1pt1"] #first file
```

If you prefer to use a list instead, you can do this:

```
files = [None]

for i in range(1, 7+1):
    files.append(open("C:/f1startsw{}.txt".format(i), "w"))

files[1] #first file
```

Comment: Why "7+1", why not just 8? =)

Comment: It's just to make it clearer how the lists are indexed. It's not necessary if you have a good handle over how off-by-one errors and indices, and it doesn't have any significant impact on performance, but for the purposes of answering the question I included it to make it easier :)